# Particle De - Mode or Condition of Agent?

Tags: particle-で

[image]

Can anyone explain to what my Anki Card up here is explaining when it comes to mode or condition of the agent?  I know what an agent is, but what does it mean by mode or condition?

Answer (score 2):

It means the state or the *how* of the agent, possibly the translation of 様態 and 条件 in Japanese.

The following entry in プログレッシブ和英中辞典 is relevant:

> [で](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A7/#je-50708)
>
> 9〔動作の行われる状態・条件〕
>
> 一人でそれをした
> I did it 「by myself [on my own].
>
> 傘なしで出掛けた
> He went out without his umbrella.
>
> 土足で部屋に入ってはいけない
> You can't enter the room with your shoes on.
>
> 彼女は着物姿でパーティーに行った
> She went to the party in (a) kimono.
>
> 彼は無礼な態度で見回した
> He looked around 「in a rude manner [rudely].
>
> きれいな声で歌っている
> She is singing in a lovely [pretty] voice.
>
> にこにこ顔で話し掛けてきた
> He spoke to me with a big [broad] smile.
>
> 彼は実力だけで出世した
> He succeeded in life simply on the strength of ability.